# Function turns Values to NaN unwanted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kaggle

I wrote a function to fill NaN with Values, but instead this function first fills the NaN with values and then deletes every value that was in the list before I did the function

```
def preprocessing(df):
median_male_3= df[(df["Sex"]=="male") &  (df["Pclass"] ==3 )]["Age"].median()
median_male_2= df[(df["Sex"]=="male") &  (df["Pclass"] ==2 )]["Age"].median()
median_male_1= df[(df["Sex"]=="male") &  (df["Pclass"] ==1 )]["Age"].median()
median_female_3= df[(df["Sex"]=="female") &  (df["Pclass"] ==3 )]["Age"].median()
median_female_2= df[(df["Sex"]=="female") &  (df["Pclass"] ==2 )]["Age"].median()
median_female_1= df[(df["Sex"]=="female") &  (df["Pclass"] ==1 )]["Age"].median()

def agemaking(para):
    Age=para[0]
    bookclass=para[1]
    sex=para[2]
    
    if pd.isnull(Age):
        print(train_titanic["Age"])          #want to check what happens inside
        if bookclass==3 and sex=="male":
            return median_male_3
        elif bookclass==2 and sex=="male":
            return median_male_2
        elif bookclass==1 and sex=="male":
            return median_male_1
        elif bookclass==3 and sex=="female":
            return median_female_3
        elif bookclass==2 and sex=="female":
            return median_female_2
        elif bookclass==1 and sex=="female":
            return median_female_1
        
        else:
            return Age
        
train_titanic['Age']= train_titanic[['Age','Pclass','Sex']].apply(agemaking,axis=1)
```

thats my function

[thats what i looked like before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHW91.png)
[thats the suprising result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beZnH.png)

Comment: Please do not insert code and examples as images. Take the time to copy and paste code to your question

Comment: just a quick note about your `preprocessing` function -- this is exactly what pandas is for. you can replace all of that with `df.groupby(["Sex", "PClass"])["Age"].median()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter version of your code could be:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])['Age'].transform('median'))
```

Compute the median Age per (Sex, Pclass) group and broadcast values to all rows with `transform`. Finally fill nan values with the computed value previously only and only if Age is null.